# Lost toolbar in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, toolbar

I can't seem to recover the toolbar in Dreamweaver. It's the one below the top toolbar and above the file tabs. The one that lets you easily swap between Design and Code view. It also has buttons for validating.

Changing workspaces does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 days of looking and I find it right after I ask for help.

View > Toolbars > Check all 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this Open Dreamweaver CS6 go in View > select Toolbar > and select anyone of them.

Regards